# Play Framework 2.2 - Handling Url parameters when making ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, playframework-2.2

I have a listing page to delete profiles,
if the profile is deleted I need to redirect to the same page and display a message "Profile deleted".

If it was a regular form I'd use Play Framework's @helper.form and invoke the action in the controller.
When that's the case:

In my action method I use `Redirect(controller.action).flashing("message" -> "some message")` and it works fine.
I also use `Ok(views.html.profile("some message",filledForm))` if I need to show the page with existing content, and it works fine.

However, since this is just a list I added a button and then perform an ajax call from javascript:

If it was successful then I redirect using: `window.location.replace("/profile/prof_deleted");`
I use the message `(/prof_deleted)` to show confirmation/error in profile template.
However, if the user tries reloading the page, the confirmation/error will be displayed again since it is included in the url.

I need to pass the message but I think a session is not a good option in this case, flashing is not an option here and url parameter will always displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense, if you are using AJAX for sending request for deleting object why do you want to perform common page redirect after all ?

You have two better options for this scenario (I prefer second one)

1. Don't use AJAX, just common POST request with the same route as GET i.e.: `/profiles` then when sending POST it deletes object and shows message, otherwise shows list of profiles only.
2. Use AJAX properly: at `success` state just remove the item from HTML using JavaScript, display message box also with JavaScript but do NOT reload the whole page.

   - For deleting required item you just need to give them unique ID, i.e.: `profile_123`
   - There are some ready-to-use, nice libs for displaying info messages via JS, i.e.: [**noty**](http://ned.im/noty/)

Comment: That's right. In the end I applied the II one. Thx for your help.